# React Spring Not Responsive/Breaking when resizing

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I am using Vite+React for a landing page and for animations I am using `@react-spring/web`.

I applied simple animations using `useSpring` and `animated` for opacity . It works when viewing in full display but not working when the screen is resized .

[Here is the code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VA4d.png)

Comment: It would be better if you could add your code snippet and more details. So then others can have a understanding of the content and answer